# ViewPager ListView in LinearLayout. Swiping ViewPager should swipe whole page?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

I have horizontal image `ViewPager` and `ListView` inside `RelativeLayout`. `ViewPager` is of fixed size and at top of screen. And below `ViewPager` I have `ListView`. But when I try to scroll up in `ViewPager`, it does not scroll whole page up.
I want to scroll whole page when up/down in `ViewPager`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentViewPager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:autoStart="true"
        android:flipInterval="10"
        android:scaleType="center">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fragmentViewPager"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like:

```
    viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return false;
    }
});
```

This way you will able to manage the scrolldown event.

Comment: Scrollable listview within a larger scrollable view (to include the listview and viewpager) is highly discouraged